# Is it possible to write a _Static_assert in GCC/GNU C that would verify the layout of bit fields in memory at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc, assertion, bit-fields, static-assert

Suppose that I have the following definitions:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define ASSERT(cond) _Static_assert(cond, #cond)

typedef union {
    struct {
        bool bit0:1;
        bool bit1:1;
        bool bit2:1;
        bool bit3:1;
        bool bit4:1;
        bool bit5:1;
        bool bit6:1;
        bool bit7:1;
    };
    uint8_t bits;
} byte;

ASSERT(sizeof(byte) == sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Is it possible to write a code, such as

```
#include <assert.h>
// ...
    assert(((byte) { .bit0 = 1 }).bits == 0b00000001);
    assert(((byte) { .bit1 = 1 }).bits == 0b00000010);
    assert(((byte) { .bit2 = 1 }).bits == 0b00000100);
    assert(((byte) { .bit3 = 1 }).bits == 0b00001000);
    assert(((byte) { .bit4 = 1 }).bits == 0b00010000);
    assert(((byte) { .bit5 = 1 }).bits == 0b00100000);
    assert(((byte) { .bit6 = 1 }).bits == 0b01000000);
    assert(((byte) { .bit7 = 1 }).bits == 0b10000000);
// ...
```

that would cause a *compile-time failure* if the above conditions weren't satisfied?

(When I try to place the conditions in the `ASSERT` macro, the compiler complains that `expression in static assertion is not constant`, which of course makes perfect sense)

The solution is allowed to use the GNU extensions to the C language.

Comment: Keep in mind endianness, see for example: http://mjfrazer.org/mjfrazer/bitfields/
So on architectures with different endian the result will be different.
Maybe this also plays a part in whether the preprocessor can tell what the result will be.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can.
`_Static_assert` is required to verify that the argument expression satisfies standard C's requirements for an integer constant expression.

There are ways, which on gcc can *sometimes* turn a boolean expression that doesn't satisfy those requirements but are compile-time-known to the optimizer into a compile-time error or warning.

E.g., :

```
#include <assert.h>
#if  __GNUC__ && !__clang__
#define $SassertIfUCan0(X) \
    (__extension__({ /*ellicit a -Wvla-larger-than */ \
         (!__builtin_constant_p(X)) ? 0 : \
        ({ char volatile $SassertIfUCan0_[ (!__builtin_constant_p(X)||(X))  ? 1:-1]; \
         $SassertIfUCan0_[0]=0,0;}); \
        __auto_type $SassertIfUCan0 = X; \
         assert($SassertIfUCan0); \
         0; \
    }))
#endif

int main(int C, char **V)
{
    int x = 0; $SassertIfUCan0(x);
    //these also ellicit compile-time errrors:
    /*$SassertIfUCan0(C-C);*/
    /*$SassertIfUCan0(C*0);*/
}
```

can turn the nullness of the compile-time known variable `x`, which isn't technically an integer constant, into a compile/time warning/error
(`"-Wvla-larger-than"`).

Unfortunately, the macro doesn't work with every expression and that includes your bitfield-based example.

(I wish compilers had a mechanism for failing compilation if an expression happens to be compile-time known and false.)

So AFAIK, the closest thing you can do is compile-time detect platforms whose ABI is known to guarantee your required bitfield layout:

```
#if __linux__ && __x86_64__
#elif 0//...
//...
#else
   #error "bitfields not known to be little-endian"
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, this is an X-Y problem: You are asking about checking the layout of bitfields when you really want to write code that is portable across different implementations of bitfields. So:

- If you don't try to communicate your bitfield to another machine, or store it in a file where a different machine may read it, just forget about the implementation detail of how the bits are ordered. Just access them via the bitfield names, and be done with it.
- If you need to communicate the structures containing these bitfields, declare a `uint8_t` and the appropriate set of bit flag constants (`#define BIT7 (1u << 7)`, etc.). Bytes never change value when they are transferred from one machine to another, so `myFlags & BIT7` is guaranteed to yield the same result everywhere.

  Note that it is important to either use a single byte to store the flags, or handle the problem of endianess explicitly.

Comment: The original context of the problem is an embedded system, where pin numbers are mapped according to the documentation. Of course it is possible to use bit operations (which is the way it's typically done), but this doesn't allow to use the basic facilities of the type system (e.g. `enum`), which results in code that is not self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

On GNU Linux, you might find `<features.h>` and `/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/linux/byteorder/big_endian.h`

> The solution is allowed to use the GNU extensions to the C language.

With most *recent* GCC compilers, **you could provide your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)** defining your `__your_builtin_endian__` compiler builtin. Notice that some GCC compilers are [built](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) without plugin support (e.g. RedHat did that). Check by running `gcc -v` alone.

Once your plugin defines `__your_builtin_endian__`, you could use that in `static_assert`. Or have your plugin define and implement some `#pragma MYPLUGIN check endian` which would make a compile-time error in some cases.

Do budget a few weeks of fulltime work for such a plugin. It is GCC version specific (not always the same C++ code for a [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) and [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) plugin).

Consider also using [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) (at least if you do not need any [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)).

Comment: The specific problem here is that the code is for an embedded system, so it needs to be cross-compiled. The way I am dealing with this now is that I have a test build of firmware, which checks assertions in runtime (which is irritating, as the information is available in compile time). What I am thinking about right now is to write a test suite, which checks the content of the generated assembly, but I'm afraid that this additional stage might also be a PITA in the long run.

Comment: Writing a GCC plugin might take no more time than checking the assembler code. You could use that plugin just once.

Comment: @MaciekGodek Generating macros describing the target platform (either by running code on the target or by inspecting generated assembly) is a tried and true way of dealing with problems like this.

Comment: @MaciekGodek, Basile: just use `__BYTE_ORDER__` and compare it to `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I believe they are not in the C++ standard

Comment: They're not, but neither are GCC builtins. (Also, this question is about C, not C++)

Answer (score 0):

Not strickly within the limits of the question, but may provide for more portable solution.

The static assertion has limits to the expressions, and it will NOT be able to evaluate expression from a union.

As an alternative, and assuming the code will be built by a makefile (or equivalent), consider adding a a step to the build to force the condition

```
static.verify: static_check.c
    cc -o static_check static_check.c
    ./static_check
    touch $@

    # Make the static.verify dependency for building objects/executable.
a.o: static.verify
```

Basically, making it a requirement to run the small program 'static_check.c'. The program can produce any required error message. Should exit with non-zero return status to indicate an error.